Why does using Integer.parseInt on String "Integer.MAX_VALUE" fail?
I was reading in values from a file, where Integer.MAX_VALUE (as text from a text file) was used instead of a seemingly random, weirdly large number to indicate an infinite cost in a graph search algorithm. I must convert the String "Integer.MAX_VALUE" to an int, so I attempted to use the Integer.parseInt() method on it.
After looking through Java's implementation of Integer.parseInt(), I noticed that the dot character ('.') wasn't an accepted character, making me think that trying to convert the String would throw an error; I was right, as per the error given by the below code.
Is there a particular design choice reason for not converting "Integer.MAX_VALUE" to the int value Integer.MAX_VALUE? Is it a "running inputs as code" String interpretation vulnerability? Is it an oversight?
Note: This issue also happens with "Integer.MIN_VALUE"
// FAILS TO COMPILE
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Integer.MAX_VALUE";
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
}
// Exception ...: For input String: "Integer.MAX_VALUE"
// at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
// at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
// at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)


// SUCCESSFUL WORKAROUND (focusing on the non-boilerplate code)
// [code to read from file and place it in a String called distance_str]
if(distance_str == "Integer.MAX_VALUE"){    distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;}
else{                                       distance = Integer.parseInt( distance_str );}

Edit:

I know that the 1st section of given code fails and that the implementation explains why; that is not what I am asking about.
I am asking about why the designers chose not to account for this, whether it was deliberate (if so, for what reason?) or an oversight. Btw, "because the method doesn't say it accounts for the max and min values as Strings" is not an acceptable answer to me due to it being a tautology. I'm asking why it is the way it is, not how it is.
Also, my usage of str1==str2 instead of str1.equals(str2) was erroneous as I was not intending to look for a memory address equivalence comparison; thank you all for correcting me on that :)


because it is not in the contract of the method. It specifies that all characters must be digit of the specified radix. No where does it say that it will read a string of Integer.MAX_VALUE and treat it as it is. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

Notably, distance_str == "Integer.MAX_VALUE" is already suspect code for Java.

"Integer.MAX_VALUE" is a string and it could not be parsed to an integer - hence the error. To get the value from the Integer.MAX_VALUE, a constant field, you can assign to an integer as: int  maxVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;.

Be careful about comparing strings with ==.  It's almost always the wrong thing to do.  You could try using the equals method instead.

To answer your question directly, "Integer.MAX_VALUE" isn't a number, so it can't parse it. Integer.MAX_VALUE is code, not a number. There is a difference between "parsing" and "evaluating". As for . being an unaccepted character, well, you're using Integer, not Double or the like. Integers don't have decimals.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal

As an aside, your code doesn't fail to compile. It will compile just fine, it will just produce an exception at run time.

@MarkRotteveel Ooh, you're totally right. Thank you for that! /gen

Documentation
You can clearly find it in the documentation of the Integer.parseInt(String).

The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value

Intend
The Integer.parseInt() method expects a string representation of a numerical value.
Example:
String s = "" + Integer.MAX_VALUE ;
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);

Is basically what you are intending to achieve.
In this case, the String s has value of 2147483647
What is wrong?
While in your case:
String s = "Integer.MAX_VALUE"

Has a value of Integer.MAX_VALUE that is a literal string, not a numerical representation.

As others have already said, you can't parse the string "Integer.MAX_VALUE", because Integer.parseInt only supports numeric values without decimals that fit inside the range of Integer.MIN_VALUE (-2147483648) and Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647).
Your workaround of first checking for the string "Inter.MAX_VALUE" is the only way to do it. You just need to use .equals instead of ==, as others have also said before.
With a ternary expression you can make it a bit less verbose:
int distance = "Integer.MAX_VALUE".equals(distance_str) ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : Integer.parseInt(distance_str);

Note that I use the string constant on the left-hand side. That's usually a good practice, because it prevent a NullPointerException if the string variable to compare against is null. In this case it won't matter much though, because Integer.parseInt also will throw an exception if the string to parse is null.
